# When is a function a convex conjugate?

Tags: banach-spaces, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space; $X^*$ be its dual; and $g:X^*\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ be a proper, convex, weak${}^*$-lower semicontinuous function with weak${}^*$-compact effective domain.

Question: Is there a known characterization of when $g$ is/isn't the convex conjugate of some (proper, convex, lower semicontinuous) $f:X\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$?

Failing that, I would love any sufficient conditions for $g$ to admit such a representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, every proper, convex, weak*-lower semi-continuous function is a conjugate. In fact, it is the conjugate of its *pre-conjugate*
$$
f(x) = \sup_{x^*\in X^*} \langle x^*,x\rangle - g(x^*).
$$

Comment: I don't think that this is true (unless $X$ is reflexive). The conjugate of the preconjugate is always weak-* lower semicontinuous. Hence, you have to assume at least that $g$ is weak-* lower semicontinuous.

Comment: True - and luckily, that's exactly what was asked for… Thanks for the catch!